# Doctrine MongoDB ODM search in two or more fields

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-odm, odm

I would like to write a query in Doctrine Mongo ODM that searches by regex in two or more fields. In SQL it would look like:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE name LIKE %search% OR surname LIKE %search%;
```

I can write a query for one field like this:

```
$qb->field('surname')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$this->search.'.*/i'));
```

but I'm at a loss when i try to search in more fields.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

well actually it is quite simple, i found out 5 mins after posting this question

```
$qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('surname')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$this->search.'.*/i')));
$qb->addOr($qb->expr()->field('name')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$this->search.'.*/i')));
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the $or operator. I'm not sure how this is done in doctrine but you are looking for the equivalent of this in the shell:

```
db.people.find({ $or: [{surname: /^regex1/}, {surname: /^regex2/}] })
```

Comment: Also, be aware that indexes will only be used for rooted case sensitive regular expressions.